# How do you declare a database default in prisma using @default and degenerated()?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, prisma-graphql, prisma2

would like to declare a default binary value in the resulting sql migration file.

I have tried using `@default(dbgenerated(“UUID_TO_BIN(uuid())”)` but the expression does not get implemented in the resulting SQL file.

Comment: Let me know if you have found the solution to this problem .

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `@default(dbgenerated("(UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()))"))`

Added one more parentheses around the function.

The model in the `schema.prisma` file will be like this

```
model user {
  id   Bytes  @default(dbgenerated("(UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()))")) @db.Binary(16)
  name String @db.VarChar(100)
}
```

If `@db.Binary(16)` is not mentioned, the default data type in the schema will be `LONGBLOB`.

Use `SELECT BIN_TO_UUID(id) FROM user` to view the actual UUID.